# What's the link to my DevOps repo for integration with Git?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm using Git to pull a remote branch. My project name is AZ and the name of the repo is Working. My assumption was the link would be **https://AltaZia.visualstudio.com/AZ** but when trying to pull from that location I get a "fatal: not a git repository" error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you clone the git repository correctly from azure and are you in the correct folder?

Comment: how do I know the answer to either of these questions? please give steps

Comment: Do you remember running the `git clone URL` command in your folder?  If not, you would need to do that first to associate that folder you are working in to the git repo in azure.  To get the URL, go to your repository in visualstudio.com, on the left hand side, click [repos] and then on the far right, click clone icon

Comment: where is the clone icon? what does it look like?

Comment: the clone icon in on the far right in your repository, under repos, it has the word 'Clone' on it.  I don't know how to attach pics on here but if you followed the note i provided earlier, it will get you there:

To get the URL, go to your repository in visualstudio.com, on the left hand side, click [repos] and then on the far right, click clone icon

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you tried to run a git command but you are not in a Git repository. You can use

```
git status
```

[Check this out](https://www.datree.io/resources/git-error-fatal-not-a-git-repository)

OR
If you're stuck with a URL to pull from, then

[Check this out](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/131432811/GitHub+-+Tips+on+Finding+Git+GitHub+Repository+URLs)

Comment: git status = "on branch master"

git config --get https://AltaZia.visualstudio.com/AZ = "error: invalid key"

Comment: Are you trying to clone a repository?

Comment: i just want to download the files from source control